# Download PDF file in same window

Tags: jquery

I have a function:

```
 function AgendaMinutes(id) {
    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="AgendaMinutes" target="_blank">');
    form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="dprid" value="' + id + '">'));
    $(body).append(form);
    form.submit().remove();
    return false;
}
```

This works fine, creates a new tab and waits until the PDF is sent to the browser then closes the tab and asks the user to open or save the document.  Is there any way of not using a new tab but yet displaying a waiting message in the current window then remove the message when the doc arrives?

Answer (score 0):

Change `target="_blank"` to `target="_self"`

i.e.

```
var form = $('<form method="POST" action="AgendaMinutes" target="_self">');
```

*_blank*: Opens the linked document in a new window or tab

*_self* : Opens the linked document in the same tab where it was clicked